# PhoneGap iOS Switching windows

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I'm having a problem switching windows in my iOS PhoneGap app. I'm currently using

```
window.changePage = "abt.html";
```

to change my view (tried some other too like 
             `$.mobile.changePage("abt.html", null, true, true);` or
            `window.open('abt.html', '_self');` )

The screen loads but I always get a small bar at the bottom of the screen, displaying the opened URL, a "Done"-Button and a forwards/backwards arrow.

Obviously it seems I'm using the wrong method, but even after researching I haven't found a way. 
Is opening new windows the wrong attempt and I only have to switch the contents of the view?

Since I'm new to all this (as some of you might have suggested already) I would appreciate any help.

/edit: The original intent was to change from one view to another (like I do in normal iOS apps) when a button gets clicked.

Thanks,

blaluma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same problem. I found a solution using jQuery+Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#abt').click(function(){
    $('body').empty();
      $.ajax({
                     url:'abt.html',
                     cache:false
                     }).done(function(html){
                                        $("body").append(html);
                                     });
                    });
});
```

I'm now just removing my html-body and insert my new-html-body instead.

/edit: After some time working me into it, I'd suggest using jQueryMobile defining pages in HTML with id's and referencing them with an href.

Example:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="SomeID">
     <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
     </div>
     <div data-role="content">
       <a href="#SomeOtherID" data-transition="slide"> </a>
     </div>
     <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
     </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="SomeOtherID">
     <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
     </div>
     <div data-role="content">
       <a href="#SomeID" data-transition="slide"> </a>
     </div>
     <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
     </div>
    </div>
```

Hope that helps someone.